# Alternative for Obsolete -VhdDestinationPath Parameter

Tags: hyper-v, powershell

I am trying to import a virtual machine with PowerShell and I want to specify which folder the VHD file should be placed in. According to http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848495.aspx the  -VhdDestinationPath parameter is obsolete. However, I can't seem to find what the alternative is. I know this parameter still works but it would be nice to know how it should be done.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that there is no alternative to the `-VhdDestinationPath` parameter at this time, but the good news is that it still works.

Another kludge would be to copy the files to their final destination, edit the VHD paths (*pathname* node) in the exported XML, and then call `Import-VM` with the `-Register` option.  The `-Register` option will leave the files in place.